# Hebrew text of Ramban on Leviticus 19,19

Tags: halacha, rashi, translation

The reason for forbidden mixtures is that God created species in the world - in all of those with spirits, in plants and in animate beings - and gave them the ability to reproduce, such that the species survive with them forever, so long as He, may He be blessed, wants the world to exist. So He commanded that they be able to produce according to their species, and that they never ever change; as it is stated about all of them, "according to its species" (Genesis 1). And this is the reason that we breed animals one with the other; for the continuation of the species - just as men have conjugal relations with women in order to be fruitful and multiply. And one who crosses two species together, changes and denies [God's] act of creation, as if he is thinking that the Holy One, blessed be He, did not perfect His world completely, and he wants to help with His creation of the world [by] adding creatures to it.
(Ramban on Leviticus 19,19)

Can anyone please give me the precise Hebrew text of "these" words? Shalom.

Answer (score 3):

Here, [from Sefaria](https://www.sefaria.org/Ramban_on_Leviticus.19.19?lang=bi), is the original Hebrew that the English segment you quote is a translation of:

> והטעם בכלאים כי השם ברא המינים בעולם בכל בעלי הנפשות בצמחים ובבעלי נפש התנועה ונתן בהם כח התולדה שיתקיימו המינים בהם לעד כל זמן שירצה הוא יתברך בקיום העולם וצוה בכחם שיוציאו למיניהם ולא ישתנו לעד לעולם שנאמר בכולם "למינהו" (בראשית א) והנה צוה סיבת המשכב שנרביע בהמות זו עם זו לקיום המינין כאשר יבואו האנשים על הנשים לפריה ורביה והמרכיב שני מינין משנה ומכחיש במעשה בראשית כאילו יחשוב שלא השלים הקב"ה בעולמו כל הצורך ויחפוץ הוא לעזור בבריאתו של עולם להוסיף בו בריות

You can click the link above to find the larger comment this section is a piece of, in Hebrew with English translation.